# How to extract common lines in AWS CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a template and I noticed there are a lot of duplicating lines.

```
GetStatusLambda:
Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
Properties:
  Code:
    S3Bucket: test-deployments
    S3Key:
      Fn::Join: [ "/", [
        test-lambdas,
        Ref: FileNameParameter
      ]]
  Handler: 'test.lambdasEntryPoint::getStatus'
  Runtime: java8
  MemorySize : 512
  Role:
    Fn::GetAtt: [LambdaRole, Arn]
  Description: Lambda attached to get status API
  Timeout: 30

SubmitInformationLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: test-deployments
        S3Key:
          Fn::Join: [ "/", [
            test-lambdas,
            Ref: FileNameParameter
          ]]
      Handler: 'test.lambdasEntryPoint::submitInformation'
      Runtime: java8
      MemorySize: 512
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt: [LambdaRole, Arn]
      Description: Lambda attached to Submit Information API
      Timeout: 30
```

Is there a way to extract the duplication sections like Code, Runtime, MemorySize, Timeout, and use Fn:Sub ot Fn:GetAtt to call them?

Answer (score 0):

The verbosity of CloudFormation tempates is well-known and a little sad, but largely unavoidable. Unfortunately the only ways to reduce the duplication are to use nested stacks, or some form of preprocessing.  You could do preprocessing either locally using your IDE or build pipeline, or after the template is uploaded to AWS using [Custom Transforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-section-structure.html).

At least CloudFormation templates can now be written in YAMl; prior to [September 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/09/aws-cloudformation-introduces-yaml-template-support-and-cross-stack-references/) they had to be written in JSON, which made them even *more* verbose...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot duplicate or reference blocks, but you can use a `Parameters` section to define variables and then use them in your `Resources` section. However, be careful trying to over due this as it can make your CloudFormation templates hard to read and maintain.

```
Parameters:
  MemorySizeParameter:
    Type: String
    Default: 512
    Description: Memory size in MB
```

The use a line like this in your Resource section:

```
MemorySize:
   Ref: MemorySizeParameter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  GetStatusLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: 'test.lambdasEntryPoint::getStatus'
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt: [LambdaRole, Arn]
      Description: Lambda attached to get status API
      Fn::Transform:
        Name: "AWS::Include"
        Parameters:
          Location: "s3://somebucket/include-partials/lambda-partials.yaml"
  SubmitInformationLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: 'test.lambdasEntryPoint::submitInformation'
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt: [LambdaRole, Arn]
      Description: Lambda attached to Submit Information API
      Fn::Transform:
        Name: "AWS::Include"
        Parameters:
          Location: "s3://somebucket/include-partials/lambda-partials.yaml"
```

The lambda-partials.yaml file will contain:

```
Code:
  S3Bucket: test-deployments
  S3Key:
    Fn::Join: [ "/", [
      test-lambdas,
      Ref: FileNameParameter
    ]]
Runtime: java8
MemorySize : 512
Timeout: 30
```